# How to get the data from table in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, html-table

I am sending a dictionary from views file to a django template.In Django template I am creating a table using the dictionary values.My requirement is to have a "download" button under the table so that when I click the button table should get download in excel sheet?? How  to achieve this?

Template:

```
{% for set_name,set_value in pass_test_results.items %}
    <table id="final_result">
        <tr id="top-grad">
            <td colspan='4'> Ip-Address : {{set_value.ip_address}}</td>
            <td> ScanTime : {{set_value.scan_time}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="table-second-top-grad">
            <th>Operating system</th>
            <th>Software</th>
            <th>Bulletin number</th>
            <th>MainKb</th>
            <th>SubKB</th>
        </tr>

        {% if set_value.missing_updates %}
            {% for category, cat_value in set_value.missing_updates.items %}
                {% if cat_value %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='5' style='background-color:#81A594;'> category : {{ category }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% for software, soft_value in cat_value.items %}
                        {% if soft_value %}
                            {% for main_kb, kb_info in soft_value.items%}
                                {% if kb_info %}
                                    <tr>
                                        {% if category == 'OS' %}
                                            <td>{{ software }}</td>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <td>{{ kb_info.os }}</td>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <td>{{ software }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ kb_info.b_no }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ main_kb }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ kb_info.sub_kb_list|unordered_list }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan='5' style='background-color:#D74B4B;'>Error Messsage : </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    </table>
    </br>
    <input class="download_button" value="Download" type="submit" name="table_download"/>
    <input class="save_to_repo_button" value="Save In Database" type="submit" name="table_save_to_repo"/>
    </br></br>
{% endfor %}
```

Views.py:

```
final_dict = {
    'set_1':{ 
        'missing_updates' :{
            'office': {}, 
            'OS': {u'Windows Vista Service Pack 0': {'123456': {'b_no': 'MS12-098', 'sub_kb_list': ['123456', '789568']}}}, 
            'Servers': {}, 
            'applications': {u'Windows media player 11.0': {'555555': {'os': '', 'b_no': 'MS13-087', 'sub_kb_list': ['222222', '1111111']}}}, 
            'IE': {u'Internet Explorer 7': {'78787878': {'os': 'Windows Vista Service Pack 0', 'b_no': 'MS13-045', 'sub_kb_list': ['000000', '11111111111']}, '67676767': {'os': '', 'b_no': 'MS13-100', 'sub_kb_list': ['343434', '11212121']}}}, 
            'Tools': {u'DotNet 2.0 SP2': {'999999': {'os': '', 'b_no': 'MS12-086', 'sub_kb_list': ['8888888', '777777']}, '123456': {'os': 'Windows Vista Service Pack 0', 'b_no': 'MS12-086', 'sub_kb_list': ['456789']}}, u'DotNet 3.0 SP2': {'975467': {'os': '', 'b_no': 'MS13-076', 'sub_kb_list': ['975467', '12467']}}}
        },
        'ip_address': '192.168.65.120', 
        'scan_time': '2013-12-10 07:46:36+00:00', 
    }
}

return render(request, 'final_output.html', {'pass_test_results': final_dict})
```

Comment: Show us what have you done? or it is just the concept upto now?

Comment: What JS-framework are you use?

Comment: show us your actual code please

Comment: Added code..
There will be multiple set of dictionaries in final_dict for each set I am creating table and keeping download button?

Comment: May I suggest using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)? There's a built-in plugin for it called [table-tools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) for transforming your table into excel files.